# Add datatables with different or equal columns, to a master datatable and show that on datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a quite peculiar problem, but I'll try to explain as clearly as possible.

I have matrices that might have different columns, but also will definitely have **some** that are the same. Here is an example:

Matrix 1 columns: Block Number | Angle | Torque

Matrix 2 columns: Block Number | Angle | Torque | Speed

My data can have more than 2 matrices, but this is just to give an idea.

**What I would like to achieve:**

Out of all my data matrices, I would like to create a master datatable, which I will then pass on to my datagridvie'w datasource. It isn't as simple as adding data though, since for the above example, I would like to know that the Speed column belongs to the second matrix, and when I filter for speed for example, I get rows from the second matrix.

One first idea I have is the following:
1) Start with the first data matrix, read all the column names, create a new datatable just with these column names:

```
DataTable Master = new DataTable();
Master.Columns.Add("Block Number");
Master.Columns.Add("Angle");
Master.Columns.Add("Torque");
```

Then start reading the data of the first matrix, and any column whose name is equal to my master datatable column name, append the rows.

2) In the above example, I would have to manually add an arbitrary value, say 0 for all the rows of Speed in the first matrix.

3) Keep doing this (adding 0's where necessary) for all my matrices. The final and easy part is to set the datagridview's datasource:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Master;
```

Do you think this is a good way to solve this? Are there more efficient alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.net - tested
I would do about the same.
Some points though: you have got be sure all datatables have the same amount of rows AND that the (for example) 50th row of dt1 corresponds with the 50th row of dt2. If not, you'll need unique keys in each table and use a more complex find-function when adding values to a row.
UPDATE : Using a unique key and no longer index-based. Cerntainly complicates the code...
In the code below I assume block number + angle make up for a unique value across all tables

```
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    dt1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("A", GetType(System.String)))
    dt1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("B", GetType(System.String)))
    dt1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("C", GetType(System.String)))
    For index = 1 To 5
        Dim nr As DataRow = dt1.NewRow
        nr("A") = index
        nr("B") = 10 + index
        nr("C") = "DT1 C value" //Guid.NewGuid.ToString
        dt1.Rows.Add(nr)
    Next

    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    dt2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("A", GetType(System.String)))
    dt2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("B", GetType(System.String)))
    dt2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("C", GetType(System.String)))
    dt2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("D", GetType(System.String)))
    For index = 3 To 7
        Dim nr As DataRow = dt2.NewRow
        nr("A") = index
        nr("B") = 10 + index
        nr("C") = "DT2 C Value" //Guid.NewGuid.ToString
        nr("D") = "DT2 value"
        dt2.Rows.Add(nr)
    Next

    Dim master As New DataTable

    Dim DTlist As New List(Of DataTable)
    DTlist.Add(dt1)
    DTlist.Add(dt2)
    //add all your datatables...
    For Each dt As DataTable In DTlist
        //add the column if needed
        For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            If master.Columns.Contains(dc.ColumnName) Then
                Continue For
            Else
                Dim newColumn As New Data.DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, GetType(System.String))
                newColumn.DefaultValue = "NonExistent"
                master.Columns.Add(newColumn)
            End If
        Next
        // add the values
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim xpression As String = String.Format("A = {0} AND B = {1}", dr("A"), dr("B"))
            Dim foundRows() As DataRow = master.Select(xpression)
            If foundRows.Count = 0 Then
                // add a new datarow to the master
                // value = NonExistent if it//s a datacolumn from the master, that isn//t in the current datatable
                Dim newRow As DataRow = master.NewRow
                For Each dc As DataColumn In master.Columns
                    If dt.Columns.Contains(dc.ColumnName) Then
                        newRow(dc.ColumnName) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
                    Else
                        newRow(dc.ColumnName) = "NonExistent"
                    End If
                Next
                master.Rows.Add(newRow)
            Else
                // add values to the existing rows
                For Each foundRow As DataRow In foundRows
                    For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                        If foundRow(dc.ColumnName).ToString = "NonExistent" Then
                            foundRow(dc.ColumnName) = dr(dc)
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next

    DataGridView1.DataSource = master
```

Comment: The things is my datatables can come with different amounts of rows. Unless I was to manually make them equal between all tables.

Comment: I think  Dim foundRows() As DataRow = master.Select(xpression) should be  Dim foundRows() As DataRow = dt.Select(xpression)                                        But still, when I get to the last foreach, no foundRow[dc].ToString() is equal to "NonExistent". Shouldn't I be looking in the Master datatable instead?

Comment: Yeah, it should have been: foundRow(dc.ColumnName).ToString = "NonExistent". code updatet, try it out, It should work

Comment: I'm not in front of my laptop unfortunately, I will try to get it tomorrow.